# One Amazon S3 Bucket with different Policy Permissions based on File Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an Amazon S3 Bucket that currently takes mp3 and image files. I want all the mp3 to be private and only accessible  via signed URLs but the images should be public and accessible without the signed URLs.

Is this even possible. I know I could just set up another S3 bucket to handle this but I am really trying to avoid doing that. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

```
 "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::yourBucketName/*.jpg"
 ]
```

OR

```
 "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::yourBucketName/*.mp3"
  ]
```

More discussion here:

[Amazon AWS S3 IAM Policy based on namespace or tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149716/amazon-aws-s3-iam-policy-based-on-namespace-or-tag)